# TOO much that vs So much that

Tags: word-usage

> The children made so much of noise in the classroom that it disturbed the teacher.

Can I use "**too**" instead of "**so**" in this sentence.
If no, how can I rewrite this sentence with "**too**". Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't say "so much **of** noise", just "so much noise."

Comment: @stangdon -I actually copied this sentence from this source:https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-so-much-and-vs-too-much/

Comment: @Hadimsv It is a possible sentence formation syntactically, but I'm sure that it is not very idiomatic to the native speakers.

Comment: @Hadimsv That would make me very suspicious of differencebetween.com.  I suspect that "Aron" who wrote that page may not be a native speaker.

Comment: What @stangdon said. I quickly identified several erroneous / questionable usages in the linked page - definitely far too many to simply ignore as "typos". It's not written by a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely use "too", but that will give a different meaning. "So" is used to intensify an adjective. In this case, it intensifies "much":

> So much noise (=the noise is really intense)

"Too", on the other hand, is used to indicate that something exceeds some limit. In this case, we can assume that the limit is the teacher's patience.

> Too much noise (=more than the teacher can tolerate)

As a side note, usually it is "so much noise" and not "so much of noise". "Of" is usually used when the noun has a determiner, eg. "so much **of a work**".

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, actually I was searching in google this phrase: "made so much noise that" and it showed me a lot of examples but when I replaced so with too, it showed me no result, so I was thinking may be its not correct to use too in this sentence.

Comment: Can you use "so much **of a work**" in a sentence?  It does not sound right to this native speaker.  *Work* is usually uncountable.

Comment: @stangdon Not sure about that. Does "So much of **the** work" sound right?

Comment: "So much of the work done on the house was shoddy". "So much of the noise caused by that motor is due to lack of maintenance".  "So much work is too much work". So much of the noise caused by the children was due to their being over-excited about the trip. There is so much noise in my office, I cannot work.

Comment: @stangdon Technically you could use "It was so much of a work of art that...." but I feel that this usage is slightly off-topic.